# Should Chatgpt be used in a software development?

Tags: computer-science, generative-ai

I have been in the software development industry for 12 years. I have used ChatGpt for a while, and I am persuaded that using the AI to write code does not seem right... (especially for new developers).

I believe that having the facility and tool to write the code, deprives the developer (bottom line, junior developers) from learning; in fact, experience taught me that we learn by trial and error. The more we try the less we are prone to make errors, thus building our knowledge base.

My colleague sees the problem from another perspective, and considers using ChatGpt as a means to reduce development time, and optimize productivity. He sees it as a code reusability, on a big scale.

He thinks that my objection towards ChatGpt is a reluctance of adapting to change; while I see his enthusiasm towards this new technology as a momentary euphoria, and strongly believe that we cannot delegate our thinking and reasoning to AI.

Your thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: So the only way to write code is hand punching assembly instructions into cards? OK, that out of the way, how in heck does one get code that does what you want using ChatGpt?

Comment: Cut the sarcasm, then register on chatgpt and feed it with any programming question, in fact; one sample question is "How do I make an HTTP request in Javascript?"
The bot will give you the code, its detailed explanation and test cases. You can also ask him to shorten or optimize your code...

Comment: That is all well and good when your question is one with boilerplate answers to a very specific item (or, something StackOverflow likely has already if one only searched for it). Many good development environments already have specific, tested help for such things.

Comment: _"How do I make an HTTP request in Javascript?"_ Yes, that's a mechanical front end job which can be done by the bot. I believe it would take decades for the bot to do back end jobs such as flight control software for air planes. Not only it requires complex algorithms, but also advanced mathematical knowledge.

Comment: The core of software development is not limited to only "writing codes". AI currently is not at the level to do the "everything else" of software development imo.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, we really aren't at the point yet where it is safe to use AI generated code for significant things. Artificial Intelligence really isn't intelligent. There have been a number of stories lately about bugs in such code that can be devastating if left in place. See [Wired](https://www.wired.com/story/ai-write-code-like-humans-bugs/) for example.

If an AI is used as an assistant to an intelligent agent (i.e. a skilled human) it can be useful, but all of the testing and other verification measures need to be in place for it to be safe to use for anything beyond the trivial.

The problem is that the "training" of an AI as the moment is based on imperfect things and without true intelligence, including the ability to analyze risk and consequences it is, as yet, impossible to trust such things.

Don't believe the hype.

Using such tools for things like documentation, rather than code, might be safer, but only provided that it is, again, vetted by human understanding. Likewise, I could see an AI being useful in generating a test suite from a set of specifications, integrated into something like an agile development process. But those tests would also need vetting. False positives and false negatives are both problematic. But that is different from generating to code itself from the specifications, not the least of which is that "specifications" are often imperfect and, themselves, need human interpretation. Language itself isn't perfect (citation needed).

It is unclear at the moment how far or how fast we will get beyond the current state, but, at the moment, brains rule. Skilled an trained brains, of course.

Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room.

---

Note that producing the wrong code faster and cheaper isn't an advantage.

Comment: It's just a tool for improving productivity. We use these tools everyday, spell check, Grammarly, even Copilot. I work in a RAD environment writing code, anything that gets me to end is an asset but I wouldn't copy and paste from something like ChatGPT, even copilot completions are questionable. Sometimes it's just helpful to use this to get a better understanding of the problem I'm trying to solve if that makes any sense.